# Find all ids which occur once in a id column and have flag 1

Tags: database, postgresql

I want the Ids which occur only once and then should have Flag = true

Sample data:

```
Id  Flag   Value
1   true   frc
1   true   yui
2   false  tyty
3   true   yul
3   false  tuo
4   true   poi

Result:
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT a.id 
 FROM table a
 left outer join table b
 on a.id = b.id
 where a.flag = 'true'
 group by a.id
 having count(*) = 1
```